# Does OpenCascade keep reference to line number of Vertex in step file after being opened?

Tags: step, opencascade, freecad

I am using FreeCAD to analyze a STEP file. I know that FreeCAD uses OpenCascade to open STEP files. Now I would like to know for a specific vertex what the line numbers in the step file are, so that I can pass this information to another program. Is there a way to extract the line number information after a Vertex has been loaded in the OpenCascade environment?

I have read through this page: https://www.opencascade.com/doc/occt-7.0.0/overview/html/occt_user_guides__step.html but I could not find the needed info.

I would need an attribute that looks like this:

```
object.Shape.Vertexes[0].steplinenumber
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCASCADE does not offer that. Implementing a feature like this might be difficult for shapes whose definition spans more than one line. Also the benefit of such a feature would probably be limited to very rare use cases.

Comment: It's very useful information if you want to edit an existing stepfile with another program than the program you used to analyse the stepfile. (Without this info, how do you know what to edit?). However thanks for the answer.